# R parallel: rbind parallely into separate data.frames

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach, r6, rparallel

The below code produces different results on Windows and Ubuntu platforms. I understand it is because of the different methods of handling parallel processing.

Summarizing:
I cannot *`insert`* / *`rbind`* data on Linux parallely (`mclapply`, `mcmapply`) while <s>I can do it on Windows</s>.

> Thanks @Hong Ooi for pointing out that `mclapply` does not works on Windows parallely, yet below question is still valid.

Of course there are no multiple inserts to same `data.frame`, each insert is performed into separate data.frame.

```
library(R6)
library(parallel)

# storage objects generator
cl <- R6Class(
    classname = "cl",
    public = list(
        data = data.frame(NULL),
        initialize = function() invisible(self),
        insert = function(x) self$data <- rbind(self$data, x)
    )
)

N <- 4L # number of entities
i <- setNames(seq_len(N),paste0("n",seq_len(N)))

# random data.frames
set.seed(1)
ldt <- lapply(i, function(i) data.frame(replicate(sample(3:10,1),sample(letters,1e5,rep=TRUE))))

# entity storage
lcl1 <- lapply(i, function(i) cl$new())
lcl2 <- lapply(i, function(i) cl$new())
lcl3 <- lapply(i, function(i) cl$new())

# insert data
invisible({
    mclapply(names(i), FUN = function(n) lcl1[[n]]$insert(ldt[[n]]))
    mcmapply(FUN = function(dt, cl) cl$insert(dt), ldt, lcl2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
    lapply(names(i), FUN = function(n) lcl3[[n]]$insert(ldt[[n]]))
})

### Windows

sapply(lcl1, function(cl) nrow(cl$data)) # mclapply
#     n1     n2     n3     n4
# 100000 100000 100000 100000
sapply(lcl2, function(cl) nrow(cl$data)) # mcmapply
#     n1     n2     n3     n4
# 100000 100000 100000 100000
sapply(lcl3, function(cl) nrow(cl$data)) # lapply
#     n1     n2     n3     n4
# 100000 100000 100000 100000

### Unix

sapply(lcl1, function(cl) nrow(cl$data)) # mclapply
#n1 n2 n3 n4
# 0  0  0  0
sapply(lcl2, function(cl) nrow(cl$data)) # mcmapply
#n1 n2 n3 n4
# 0  0  0  0
sapply(lcl3, function(cl) nrow(cl$data)) # lapply
#     n1     n2     n3     n4
# 100000 100000 100000 100000
```

And the question:

#### How can I achieve *`rbind`* parallely into separate `data.frame`s on a Linux platform?

P.S. Off-memory storage like `SQLite` cannot be considered as solution in my case.

Comment: You do realise that mclapply doesn't actually run in parallel on Windows, right?

Comment: @HongOoi now I know. Thanks. I've rephrase question then.

Comment: One tip is to look at the `data.table` package. I know my tip doesn't answer your question directly, but still might help performance. The `data.table` package plays nicer with large data sets (GBs range) than base **`R`**'s `data.frame`s.

Comment: @RichardErickson It was data.table, I translate to data.frame just for asking question ;)

Comment: To get the same behaviour on Linux as on Windows, use lapply. It won't run in parallel, but neither does mclapply on Windows.

Comment: @RichardErickson, Jan is one of the main developers of the `data.table` package and its different extensions...

Comment: @DavidArenburg Surely not one of *main* devs, I've just pushed few small commits, you should try :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg I learn something new everyday. Thank you guys for developing the package!

Comment: Ok, I meant **Currently** you are on of the main developers

Comment: @HongOoi see [mclapply hack for windows](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2014/07/14/implementing-mclapply-on-windows/).

Comment: @jangorecki What about it? It's just using the parallel library, which has been part of base R for 4 years.

Comment: @HongOoi just linked FYI it is possible to use mclapply on windows, of course my example does not use it, but it is not the case now.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `mclapply` and `mcmapply` are not intended to be used with functions that have side effects. Your function is modifying objects in lists, but `mclapply` doesn't send the modified objects back to the master process: it only returns the values explicitly returned by the function. That means your results are lost when the workers exit as `mclapply` returns.

Normally I would change the code to not depend on side effects, and return the objects that are modified. Here's one way to do that using `clusterApply` so that it also works in parallel on Windows:

```
library(R6)
library(parallel)
cl <- R6Class(
    classname = "cl",
    public = list(
        data = data.frame(NULL),
        initialize = function() invisible(self),
        insert = function(x) self$data <- rbind(self$data, x)))

N <- 4L # number of entities
i <- setNames(seq_len(N),paste0("n",seq_len(N)))
set.seed(1)
ldt <- lapply(i, function(i)
  data.frame(replicate(sample(3:10,1),sample(letters,1e5,rep=TRUE))))
nw <- 3  # number of workers
clust <- makePSOCKcluster(nw)
idx <- splitIndices(length(i), nw)
nameslist <- lapply(idx, function(iv) names(i)[iv])

lcl4 <- do.call('c', clusterApply(clust, nameslist, 
  function(nms, cl, ldt) {
    library(R6)
    lcl4 <- lapply(nms, function(n) cl$new())
    names(lcl4) <- nms
    lapply(nms, FUN = function(n) lcl4[[n]]$insert(ldt[[n]]))
    lcl4
  }, cl, ldt))
```

This method doesn't work if you want to create the list of objects once and then modify the objects multiple times in parallel. That is also possible to do, but you must have persistent workers. In that case, you fetch the modified objects from the workers after all of the tasks are complete. Unfortunately, `mclapply` doesn't use persistent workers, so in this case you must use the cluster-based functions such as `clusterApply`. Here's one way to do it:

```
# Initialize the cluster workers
clusterEvalQ(clust, library(R6))
clusterExport(clust, c('cl', 'ldt'))
clusterApply(clust, nameslist, function(nms) {
  x <- lapply(nms, function(n) cl$new())
  names(x) <- nms
  assign('lcl4', x, pos=.GlobalEnv)
  NULL
})

# Insert data into lcl4 on each worker
clusterApply(clust, nameslist, function(nms) {
  lapply(nms, FUN = function(n) lcl4[[n]]$insert(ldt[[n]]))
  NULL
})

# Concatenate lcl4 from each worker
lcl4 <- do.call('c', clusterEvalQ(clust, lcl4))
```

This is very similar to the previous method, except that it splits the process into three phases: worker initialization, task execution, and result retrieval. I also initialized the workers in a more conventional manner using `clusterExport` and `clusterEvalQ`.

Comment: I'm impressed of the parallel R understanding! I wonder if RRO can simplify the api?

Comment: Meaning "Revolution R Open"? I've never used it, so I don't know.

Comment: @jangorecki have you tried using `data.table::rbindlist`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik yes but the goal was to distribute this work over a cluster of machines. I am aware `rbindlist` is extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think that windows version of `mclapply` is working because it delegates its job to `lapply`. Checking timings or cpu core usage can verify this. According to [R source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/parallel/R/windows/mcdummies.R), Windows `mclapply` and `mcmapply` are substituted with sequential versions.

It seems, something is wrong with how code is parallelized, can't see what exactly at the moment.

Comment: `mclapply` on Linux uses the `fork` system call to make a clone of the current R process. This call doesn't exist on Windows, hence `mclapply` reverts back to sequential behaviour.